# Capturing image using getUserMedia and drawing it to canvas

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

> > I am using getUserMedia HTML 5 feature to stream video to video tag.Using canvas the image from < video > tag is drawn to canvas.In my
> >     case I can draw only one image at a time on canvas.Lets say I click multiple times Camera button, in this
> >     case latest image will be drawn on canvas.
> >     How I want to do is:
> >     draw multiple images to canvas > dynamically generate canvas elements to capture multiple screenshots.

Kindly suggest any way to achieve the same.

Thanks

```js
var videoStream = null;
var video = document.getElementById("video");
var createSrc = window.URL ? window.URL.createObjectURL : function(stream) {
  return stream;
};

document.getElementById('camera').addEventListener('click', function() {
  navigator.getUserMedia({
      video: true,
      audio: false
    },
    function(stream) {

      videoStream = stream;
      // Stream the data
      video.src = createSrc(stream);
      video.play();
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code);
      alert("error in streaming");
    });

});
document.getElementById('screenshot').addEventListener('click', function() {

  var canvas = document.querySelector('#tagCanvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
  canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
  try {
    var imageUrl = canvas.toDataURL();

  } catch (e) {
    alert("Error in getting canvas url");
  }


});
```

```html
<video id="video" autoplay="autoplay" style="background-color: lightgray; 
     width:80%; height:60%; margin-top:-4em">
</video>
<canvas id="tagCanvas" style="background-color: gray; width: 50%">
</canvas>
<button data-theme="d" id="screenshot">Screen Shot</button>
<button data-theme="d" id="camera">Start Camera</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you are selecting the canvas you have on screen:

`var canvas = document.querySelector('#tagCanvas');`

Replace with the creation of a canvas element:

`var canvas = document.createElement("div");`

Place it on the page:

`document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(canvas);`

Remembering to set the correct styles, widths and heights so the canvas can be seen.

Comment: using var canvas = document.createElement("div"); , video stream is not capturing on div tag

Answer (score 0):

You can draw multiple screen captures per canvas, if that's what you need:

**The javascript**

```
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var cw=canvas.width;
    var ch=canvas.height;

    var position=0;

        var v = document.getElementById('v');
        v.addEventListener( "loadedmetadata", function(e){
            // resize canvas
            cw=canvas.width=v.videoWidth;
            ch=canvas.height=v.videoHeight;
            // play the video
            v.play();
        }, false );   


    $('#snap').click(function(){

        var x,y;
        if(position==0){ x=0;y=0; }
        if(position==1){ x=cw/2;y=0; }
        if(position==2){ x=0;y=ch/2; }
        if(position==3){ x=cw/2;y=ch/2; }

        ctx.clearRect(v,x,y,cw/2,ch/2);
        ctx.drawImage(v,x,y,cw/2,ch/2);

        position++;
        if(position>3){ position=0; }

    });

}); // end $(function(){});
```

**The HTML**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<button id=snap>Capture</button>
<br>
<h4>Captured Snapshots -- 4 snapshots per canvas</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
<h4>Video Element below</h4>
<video id=v controls loop>
    <source src=yourClip.mp4 type=video/mp4>
</video>
```

Comment: Nice. Since all the screen shots are on a single canvas element, how only one can be selected and converted to toDataUrl()

Comment: To reduce any of the 4-up drawings to an image you can: (1) Create a new in-memory canvas sized to fit one of the 4-up drawings using `document.createElement`, (2) Use the clipping version of `drawImage` to clip one of the 4-up drawings from the main canvas to the in-memory canvas, (3) Use `toDataURL` to convert the in-memory canvas to a dataURL, and (4) use that dataURL as the image source for a `new Image`. And you have success! Good luck with your project!

Comment: Did you mean to create 4 canvas element? or loop through document.createElement

Comment: Well yes, my example shows one canvas with 4 images--kind of like the way security cameras have 4 images per display screen. But alternatively, you could create a new canvas for each captured snapshot if you need to. To do that you would just `document.createElement('canvas')` instead of drawing to the one canvas.

Comment: Ok. Done. Lets say user want to choose best screen shots out of 4, virtually all 4 canvas are not visible to user(created dynamically), instead a single canvas on page holds all 4 screenshots. How one can select best shot from single canvas containing all screenshots and depending upon user's selection the corresponding newly created canvas should be converted to toDataURL .

Comment: Since each snapshot takes up half the canvas width and half the canvas height, you could listen for mouse clicks and calc which quadrant the mouse is in. (Given mx,my as mouse and cw,ch as canvas width,height) UpperLeft when mx<cw/2 && my<ch/2, UpperRight when mx>cw/2 && my<ch/2, BottomLeft when mx<cw/2 && my>ch/2, BottomRight when mx>cw/2 && my>ch/2. Then convert that quadrant to an in-memory canvas as I outlined above :-)

Comment: Very descriptive explanation. Thank you Mark.